# Client-side event when Node server comes online

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my client-side node code, I have something like this:

```
var socket = io('//localhost:1337');

$(function() {
    if ( !socket.connected )
        NodeOfflineError();
});
```

Now, let's say I had a `NodeBackOnlineAlert()` function to go along with the `NodeOfflineError()` function, how would I know when to call it?

Is there a listener for the polling that checks whether the server is live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have listeners that run the function and have a function to reconnect when the socket is disconnected:

```
socket.on("disconnect", function() {
                    NodeOfflineError();
                    socket.socket.reconnect();

                });

socket.on("connect", function() {
                NodeOnlineAlert()
                });

socket.on("reconnect", function() {
                NodeBackOnlineAlert()
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the listener events of socket io (assuming you use socket io)

```
const socket = io('//localhost:1337')
$(() => {
    socket.on('connected', socket => {
        console.log('connected!')

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            NodeOfflineError()
        })
    })

    socket.on('reconnect', () => {
        NodeBackOnlineAlert()
    })
})
```

http://socket.io/docs/ Check the part where it says 'Sending and receiving events' also http://socket.io/docs/client-api/ :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Server Sent Events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events. The MDN guide should have everything you need to implement them (they're quite simple!).  This library might prove useful for your server: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sse

Comment: Does not answer question. Very impractical if not impossible to reliably use SSE to relay real-time information about a Node connection.

Comment: @DanL actually sse is very reliable.